# Are there any operating trains in Nicaragua?

Tags: trains, nicaragua

I have heard that Nicaragua used to have an operating train system, but at some point in the past it was dismantled and discontinued. Are there currently *any* trains that regularly operate in Nicaragua? If so, are there any that a visitor could ride on?

Comment: no Nicaragua doesn't have train anymore since 90's it was sold and no goverment have been interested in starting one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Sorry, no trains.**

I am not sure about freight trains, but there are no passengers trains in Nicaragua anymore since 2001.

Wikipedia has a [page about the history of rail transport in Nicaragua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rail_transport_in_Nicaragua)

In fact there is only one passenger train in the whole of central America and that's a [tourist train](http://www.panarail.com) along the Panama canal.

Further north in Mexico there are lots of freight trains but very few [passenger trains.](http://www.mexlist.com/pass.htm)